# Yii2 Advanced Template email using Swift mailer working fine in front end but not working in back-end

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

Developing the project using Yii2 in my local xampp.Using swift mailer, email part is working fine from front-end but not working from backend, after sending the email it is not even showing the error but returning sending status as true, following is my code

Front end config,``

```
'components' => [
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'useFileTransport' => false,
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => 'xxxx,
        'username' => 'xxx,
        'password' => 'xxx',
        'port' => '465',
        'encryption' => 'ssl',                            
    ], 
  ], 
  ...............
```

back end config,

```
'components' => [
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport' => false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'cloudlinux4.ukdns.biz',
            'username' => 'sendmail@chillizonehosting.co.uk',
            'password' => 'Test091ixV2',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',                            
          ], 
        ......
```

Sample code for sending email,

```
 Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
         ->setFrom('xxxx@gmail.com')
         ->setTo('support@xx.com')
         ->setSubject('Email sent from Yii2-Swiftmailer')
         ->send();
```

Do i want to add any extra code in back-end controller or in config?, kindly help me on this.

Comment: have you checeked that local config `backend/config/main-local.php` doesn't override any mailer settings?

Comment: @csminb Thanks, the problem was at backend/config/main-local.php, it wasn't having proper components configuration settings. Now its cleared

Answer (score 0):

maybe an override setting you have in config/main-local.php on BACKEND , check  that out .

Comment: Yes it was having some other configuration code and was cleared.Thanks for your reply.:)